# How to add a legend for multiple series in ms chart c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, legend

I have been working on ASP.NET MVC razor project, C#, Visual Studio 2012. I have a chart with two series.

**My code is:**

```
var chartCentersByYear = new Chart
            {
                Width = 1000,
                Height = 450,
                RenderType = RenderType.ImageTag,
                AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.Graphics,
                TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.High


            };

            chartCentersByYear.Series.Add("Count");
            chartCentersByYear.Series.Add("Cases");
            chartCentersByYear.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column; 
            chartCentersByYear.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
var totalCentersByYearResult = new Repository().GetTotalCentersByYear();

            foreach (IGD_spInternationalReportCenterWithTots_Result item in totalCentersByYearResult)
            {
                chartCentersByYear.Series[0].Points.AddXY(item.YearEcmo, item.Count);
                chartCentersByYear.Series[1].Points.AddY(item.Cases);
            }
```

...etc. I have to insert a legend in the chart to show both series in the same legend. I need to show values next to the legend symbol, for Count 83,86,93 ... etc and for Cases 1644,1775,1933 etc for each year. How can I do that? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What charting library are you using?

Comment: I am using System.Web.DataVisualization.dll, namespace System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting and System.Drawing.dll

Answer (score 1):

```
Legend secondLegend = new Legend("MyLegend");

this.Chart1.Legends.Add("MyLegend");

// Associate Series 2 with the second legend 
chartCentersByYear.Series[0].Legend = "MyLegend";
chartCentersByYear.Series[1].Legend = "MyLegend";
chartCentersByYear.Series[2].Legend = "MyLegend";
chartCentersByYear.Series[3].Legend = "MyLegend";
```